# Error with gunzip during logrotate

Tags: debian, logrotate, gzip

I'm using logrotate to rotate my Symfony2 logs on my webserver.
Everything works fine, but I wanted the old logs to be sent to me by emails.
So, I added some line in my logrotate conf file as you can see below

**Logrotate config**

```
/var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        notifempty
        mail myemail@example.com
        su www-data www-data
}
```

Now I do get emails, but the content is not really what I expected.

**Email received**

> /etc/cron.daily/logrotate: 
>   error: mail command failed for /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.6.gz
>   error: uncompress command failed mailing /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.6.gz
>   run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1

I did many reasearch for this error but I didn't find anything usefull.
I've launched an strace in hope to gain some insight on the problem but it didn't work out as expected.

**Strace command**

```
strace -f -o ./strace.txt logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/symfony2
```

The generated file is quite big, but I think that the revelant part is the following

**Strace output**

> 6842  execve("/usr/bin/mail", ["/usr/bin/mail", "-s", "/var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod."..., "myemail@example.com"], [/* 18 vars */] 
>
>   6841  <... setgid resumed> )            = 0
>
>   6842  <... execve resumed> )            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
>   6841  setuid(0)                         = 0
>
>   6841  execve("/bin/gunzip", ["/bin/gunzip"], [/* 18 vars */] 
>   **6842  exit_group(1)                     = ?**
>   6841  <... execve resumed> )            = 0
>   6842  +++ exited with 1 +++
>   6841  brk(0 
>   6840  <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 6842
>   6841  <... brk resumed> )               = 0x85f010
>   6840  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6842, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
>   6840  write(2, "error: ", 7 
>   6841  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK 
>   6840  <... write resumed> )             = 7
>   6841  <... access resumed> )            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   6840  write(2, "mail command failed for /var/www"..., 65

As you can see, gunzip command exit with the error code 1 and some very explicit question mark (?) in order to help me better understand what is happening. The only error I'm getting is "No such file or directory" which I find very weird because logrotate is supposed to handle the files rotation before sending emails.

***My question, how to solve this problem with gunzip/logrotate in order to receive the rotated log file by email before it gets deleted ?***

Here are some information on my server that might be relevant to the problem

> root@someServer:/home/someUser# cat /etc/debian_version
>   8.1
>   root@someServer:/home/someUser# logrotate --version
>   logrotate 3.8.7
>   root@someServer:/home/someUser# gzip --version
>   gzip 1.6

Also, my logs files are quite small (~300-400 bytes) and If I use gunzip manually it works just fine.

---

**Edit - adding logrotate output**

> Handling 1 logs
>   
>   rotating pattern: /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log  forced from command line (5 rotations)
>   empty log files are not rotated, old logs mailed to someEmail@example.com
>   switching euid to 1000 and egid to 33
>   considering log /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log
>       log needs rotating
>   rotating log /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log, log->rotateCount is 5
>   dateext suffix '-2016011811'
>   glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.5.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.6.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5),
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.4.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.5.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4),
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.3.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.4.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3),
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.2.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.3.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2),
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.1.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.2.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1),
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.0.gz to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.1.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0),
>   old log /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.0.gz does not exist
>   renaming /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log to /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.1
>   compressing log with: /bin/gzip
>   switching uid to 1000 and gid to 33
>   switching uid to 1000 and gid to 33
>   switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
>   error: mail command failed for /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.6.gz
>   error: uncompress command failed mailing /var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log.6.gz
>   switching euid to 0 and egid to 0

Full strace below :

```
 strace -vf -s 128 -e verbose=all -o ./strace.txt logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/symfony2
```

http://pastebin.com/C0uj0419

Comment: Looks like a permission problem. I would try confirming this by running the command (which is available on strace output)  by hand as www-data user

Comment: @Xavy I'll try but it seems weird since logrotate has no problem to split & compress my log file (prod.log.1.gz, prod.log.2.gz....) which in theory mean that gzip (and gunzip) works fine.

Comment: @Xavy I've added a test user to the group www-data (since it's a nologin account) then I've tried to gunzip a file and it works just fine...

Comment: @GaryOlsson, can you pls post the output of: `logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/symfony2`  (-v for vervose, -f for force)

Comment: @bangal Done, hope it helps.

Comment: Can you post the entire strace output *with full parameters* printed?

Comment: @shodanshok I've added the full strace with parameters `-s 128` to print 128 characters and `-e verbose=all` option. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't see executable's parameters. Can you enable them?

Comment: @shodanshok here, I've added the option -v to strace and updated the link. But I'm not sure it's what you want, if you have specific strace option in mind it would be simplier.

Comment: I want to see the very specific `mail` and `gunzip` command executed. `mail` seems ok but, unfortunately, the `gunzip` command line is again not complete - can you extend the max characters number to something bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your strace, your problem isn't actually gzip.

Here is why gzip fails.

```
14972 write(1, "<Here is the content of my prod.log file>"..., 32768) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

The process is writing to stdout, the actual output of this however is the input to the mail command. If we check this:

```
14973 execve("/usr/bin/mail", ["/usr/bin/mail", "-s", "/var/www/symfony/app/logs/prod.log", "someUser@example.com"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "TERM=xterm", "USER=root", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41"..., "SUDO_USER=none", "SUDO_UID=1000", "USERNAME=root", "MAIL=/var/mail/root", "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "PWD=/home/none", "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8", "SHLVL=1", "SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash", "HOME=/root", "LANGUAGE=en_GB:en", "LOGNAME=root", "SUDO_GID=1000", "_=/usr/bin/strace"] <unfinished ...>
14973 <... execve resumed> )            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

When you try to execute the mail command, it fails because `/usr/bin/mail` doesn't exist. The program exits, the `stdout` of `gzip` returns `SIGPIPE` as the other end of the pipe has disappeared. Thus gzip exits with a 1.

What you need to do is install a `mail` command. Thats probably either `bsd-mailx` on debianesque systems or `mailx` on Redhat based ones.

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind that it would be possible because I was receiving an email, but it's the right answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Use a `prerotate` or `postrotate` script to send the logs yourself. This gives you the flexibility to send the logs as a compressed attachment if you prefer, or decompress them.

There are a [number of options for sending attachments from the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line).